# Escrever em nova coluna de um arquivo csv usando StringBuilder c#

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder

Vi um exemplo de um código aqui mesmo no stackoverflow onde utilizo o exemplo abaixo para escrever um arquivo CSV usando stringbuilder:

```
public void ExportarCsv(List<Result> erros)
        {
            string filename = "resultado.csv";
            string path = @"C:\Arquivo\";

            Console.WriteLine("Escrevendo no arquivo.");

            StringBuilder csvBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            //cria o header
            csvBuilder.AppendLine("Order;Motivo");

            foreach (var item in erros)
            {
                csvBuilder.AppendLine(item.CodigoPedido);
                
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            File.WriteAllText(path + filename, csvBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
        }
```

Nesse exemplo ai tenho o cabeçalho Order e Motivo, porem consigo escrever somente abaixo do Order. Como faço para escrever os valores em cada colunas respectivamente ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples... você está fazendo isso, só não está escrevendo o resto do conteúdo. Lembrando que `CSV` é um arquivo com delimitadores, não existem colunas... E no seu caso o separador é o padrão, `;`.

Ao invés de ir concatenando a seu texto para compor a linha, eu recomendo utilizar o recurso de interpolação indicado pelo símbolo `$` antes da sua `string`.

```
foreach (var item in erros)
{
    csvBuilder.AppendLine($"{item.CodigoPedido};{item.Motivo}");        
}
```

Comment: boa muito obrigado. Simples mesmo, nao estava conseguindo enxergar, valeu pela luz kkkk